# Selenium: условие IfElementPresent

Tags: python, selenium

При отправке формы если на сайте появляется искомый элемент то тест будет считаться Fail, в другом случае элемент не появиться и результат будет True.

```
def AddDevice(self):
    testName = 'Add Device.'
    mainPageObject = MainPageClass(self.driver)
    try:
        mainPageObject.createDeviceButton.click()
        mainPageObject.msgCreateDevice.waitElementToBePresent()
        mainPageObject.acceptCreateDevice.waitElementToBePresent()
        mainPageObject.acceptCreateDevice.click()
        sleep(2)

        # вот эта строчка

        mainPageObject.msgCreateDeviceError.elementIsPresent()

        # если элемент присутствует, то возвращаем False,
        # в другом случае True

        self.logger.info('Test ' + testName + ' Pass. ')
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info('Test ' + testName + ' Fail. ')
        self.driver.refresh()
        return False

def runTest(self):
    self.results = []
    self.results.extend((self.AddDevice(),))
    if all(self.results) == len(self.results):
        self.numberOfPassedCases = len(self.results)
        self.numberOfCases = len(self.results)
        self.logger.info(
            f"Test Suite {self.testName} Pass with test outcome "
            f"{self.numberOfPassedCases}/{self.numberOfCases}"
        )
        self.testResult = True
    else:
        self.numberOfPassedCases = self.results.count(True)
        self.numberOfCases = len(self.results)
        self.logger.info(
            f"Test Suite {self.testName} Pass with test outcome "
            f"{self.numberOfPassedCases}/{self.numberOfCases}"
        )
        self.testResult = False
```

Вот как выглядит эта функция проверки на наличие элемента:

```
def elementIsPresent(self):
return EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.locator))
```

Как я понимаю она возвращает True / False, но у меня не получается написать условие, при котором если элемент будет на странице - то тест провален, в другом случае выполнен.

Не получается реализовать IF/ ELSE внутри конструкции TRY

Может есть другой метод условия? подскажите, я пока новичек в программировании...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите обработку исключения в метод `elementIsPresent`, что-то типа этого:

```
def elementIsPresent(self):
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, self.locator)))
    return True
except:
    return False
```

И делайте проверки через `assert`, в случае когда элемент должен присутствовать:

```
assert mainPageObject.msgCreateDeviceError.elementIsPresent() == True
```

И когда должен отсутствовать:

```
assert mainPageObject.msgCreateDeviceError.elementIsPresent() == False
```

Comment: Я тоже много гуглил, и проверил функцию: ```from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    def elementIsPresent(self):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(By.XPATH)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True``` Мне при любых условиях возвращается `False`

Comment: Так вы же не передаете локатор в метод, попробуйте исправить так: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException def elementIsPresent(self): try: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.locator) return True except NoSuchElementException: return False`

Comment: Да, спасибо! теперь, если элемент ошибки есть на клауде, то тест возвращает False, если его нет, (элемента ошибки) то всё ОК! Спасибо. Я 2 дня с этим боролся.

Comment: Кстати, первый ваш вариант тоже подхошел, я его протестировал - работает. Но мне как-то второй более "близок"...

Comment: первый вариант будет выжидать 10 секунд(пытаться найти элемент) и только потом вызывать эксепшн, второй вариант сразу после того как не нашел вернет эксепшн

Comment: Я это предусмотрел запустив сразу после нажатия кнопки `sleep(2)` 2 секунды ожидания. Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: Советую избегать неявных ожиданий таких как `sleep(2)`, лучше используйте явные, с помощью `WebDriverWait`